# Using kernel cryptographic functions

Tags: linux-kernel, hashsum, cryptography

Is it possible to use kernel cryptographic functions in the userspace? Let's say, I don't have `md5sum` binary installed on my system, but my kernel has `md5sum` support. Can I use the kernel function from userspace? How would I do it?

Another scenario would be, if I don't trust the `md5sum` binary on my system (my system could have been compromised), but I trust my kernel (I am using cryptographically signed kernel modules).

Comment: If I have had access sufficient to subvert files in /usr/bin, then I've probably been able to subvert your kernel modules and anything else I want. Saying "I trust the kernel" in such a scenario is foolhardy.

Comment: If you had subverted the kernel modules, then my kernel would refuse to load these modules, because the cryptographic signature would not match. I thought I have made this clear in my original question.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I also overwrote your "signatures" and your kernel. The kernel is just a file, it has no magical properties, and if I've hacked your machine then no file is safe. To be more explicit, if you don't trust the md5sum file there's no reason to trust the kernel or any other file.

Comment: Overwriting the "kernel file" does not have any effect on the running kernel. You would have to restart the machine and boot into the compromised kernel. I think, I would have noticed if somebody had restarted my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this article titled: [A netlink-based user-space crypto API](http://lwn.net/Articles/410763/) it would appear that what you're proposing is possible. I'm not sure how to answer your question any further than this article though.